# Discord Bot download and then send image into channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Currently trying to program a discord bot to download an image generated from a site;

```
https://thisartworkdoesnotexist.com/
```

With the code I have the bot responds perfectly fine to the command but its not executing it right.

```
execute(message, args){
     message.channel.send({files: ["https://thisartworkdoesnotexist.com/"]});
}
```

This code just has the bot send in the html link as a downloadable exe file, im assuming I need to have the bot download the image and store it somewhere and then access it within discord to send the image in but im at a loss on how to do this and searching for help is only coming up with downloading mass images from google / other discord channels etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: does discord.js files support data urls?

Comment: i dont think it does unfortunately, not in a way that I can see anyways